# use UMD library in angular 2/4

Tags: javascript, angular, requirejs, umd

I have library ([Tus.io](http://tus.io/)) thats compiled to [UMD](https://github.com/umdjs/umd). i need it in my Angular2/4 project. when i install it with npm ( **npm install tus-js-client** ) and import it (**var tus = require("tus-js-client");** ) the error i get is:

```
Failed to compile.
/home/***/src/app/manageVideos/Partials/add.component.ts (8,17): 
Module '../../../../node_modules/tus-js-client/dist/tus.js' 
was resolved to '/home/***/node_modules/tus-js-client/dist/tus.js', 
but '--allowJs' is not set.
/home/***/src/app/manageVideos/Partials/add.component.ts (9,11): Cannot find name 'require'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution to your problem is to install the TypeScript declarations:

```
npm install @types/tus-js-client --save-dev
```

And to import it like this:

```
import * as tus from "tus-js-client";
```